# pick all positive least numbers from data set

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have below data in a table

```
ID  AMOUNT  DAYS
1   10  1
1   20  2
1   30  3
1   1   4
2   34  1
2   234 2
2   234 3
2   34  4
3   3   1
3   3   2
3   23  3
3   20  4
```

I want below results as all amounts which have least days of a ID

```
ID  AMOUNT  DAYS
1   10  1
2   34  1
3   3   1
```

Please suggest a sql query to pick this desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rank()` function

```
select ID, Amount, Days from
(
 select rank() over (partition by ID order by days) as rn,
        t.*
   from tab t
)
where rn = 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/SHIOC33630)</kbd>

Comment: What is partition by column ? and i have negative nos also how i can skip negatives

Comment: @Sami partition by is used for grouping criteria. Where's negative one by the way?

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you can simply do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.days = 1;
```

If `1` is not fixed, then a correlated subquery is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.days = (select min(t2.days) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Another method is aggregation:

```
select t.id, min(t.days) as min_days,
       min(t.amount) keep (dense_rank first order by t.days asc) as min_amount
from t
group by t.id;
```

Of course `row_number()`/`rank()` is another alternative.

With an index on `(id, days)` and a large table, one of the above methods may be faster in practice.

Answer (score 0):

First `group by id` to find the min days for each id and then join to the table

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join (
  select id, min(days) days
  from tablename
  group by id
) g on g.id = t.id and g.days = t.days
```